# To characterize large separable spaces in which every non-trivial connected subset has non-empty interior?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, metric-spaces, connectedness

$\mathbb R$ with usual metric is a space such that every connected subset with more than one point has non-empty interior . My question is , can we characterize those separable metric spaces with more than one point in which every connected subset with more than one point has non-empty interior ? Or more strongly , can we characterize those separable , infinite metric spaces in which every infinite connected subset  has non-empty interior ? More restrictively can we characterize those separable , uncountable metric spaces in which every uncountable connected subset  has non-empty interior ? And what if we loosen  all metric spaces with topological spaces ?

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $\Bbb R^2$ is not such a space, thanks to the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan).

Comment: (1)The space of rationals, or any discrete space are examples in a vacuous fashion.  Metrizable but having no connected subspace with more than one point.(2) A hedgehog space is a  metrizable, connected example. (3) Any connected linear space. (4) A hedgehog-like space made of connected linear spaces instead of  copies of R.......These examples all have small-inductive dimension 1 or 0.